# Does anyone know what the "-FC" option does in gcc g++?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

Does anyone know what the "-FC" option does in g++?

I have it in my SConstruct script that builds the command line g++ command, I have searched google

Comment: what did you search? did you not try searching gcc manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know, if all fails, read the manual :-).

> F*dir*
>
> Add the framework directory dir to the head of the list of directories to be searched for header files. These directories are interleaved with those specified by -I options and are scanned in a left-to-right order. 
>   [...]

Source: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Darwin-Options.html#Darwin-Options

So *-FC* will apparently add the framework directory "C" to the header file search path.

Comment: How did you find that!? I really did search, promise! Many thanks! ....... But, I think the flag has actually mistakenly been put in my linux build options, as in the win32 options there is "/FC" ("Full Path of Source Code File in Diagnostics" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/027c4t2s%28VS.80%29.aspx) so some idiot thought best have that in linux as well! (As we dont run on "Darwin"!) . . . .
Many thanks again.

Comment: Perhaps the problem in searching was that the manual never mentions "-FC." Rather, it only mentions "-F," and Ian didn't realize that "C" was an argument to the "-F" option. Searching for "FC" would yield no results.